# Web management service not start on reboot

Tags: iis, service, web, eventviewer, msdeploy

Server 2012R2 with management service. Whe reboot the server, the service not start automatically. If i start it manually, it start successfull. There are these events on event viewer:

Service Control Manager - Event 7024

The Web Management Service service terminated with the following service-specific error:
Unspecified error

HostableWebCore

Event 2276 - The worker process failed to initialize correctly and therefore could not be started. The data is the error.

Event 2269 - The worker process for app pool 'WMSvcAppPool', PID='1836', failed to initialize the http.sys communication when asked to start processing http requests and therefore will be considered ill by W3SVC and terminated. The data field contains the error number.

IIS-IISManager event - Event 1006

IISWMSVC_STARTUP_UNABLE_TO_ACTIVATE_HWC

Failed to activate the Hostable Web Core (HWC). Web Management Service startup failed. Please reference the Win32 error in this event for further information.

Exception:System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException (0x800704BE): The format of the specified network name is invalid. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x800704BE)
at System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.ThrowExceptionForHRInternal(Int32 errorCode, IntPtr errorInfo)
at Microsoft.Web.Management.Server.WebServer.Microsoft.Web.Management.Server.Interop.IWebServer.Start()

Process:WMSvc
User=NT AUTHORITY\LOCAL SERVICE

The deployment service works by 8172 port and have a valid certificate configured. All webs use the 80 and 443. There is only one ip configured on the server.

I installed some updates the day before, but I don't know if this is the source of the problem. I'm going to uninstall them to see if it works.

Thanks,